# Android duplicate when open with

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, mobile

Has anyone had a problem similar to the one in the image?[image: Duplicate]

I get this duplication after pt

```
 manifestPlaceholders = [
                appAuthRedirectScheme: "emyplace"
        ]
```

in my default configs, but if I remove it, i getting the error:

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute data@scheme at AndroidManifest.xml requires a placeholder substitution but no value for  is provided.

Comment: try delete aother app with same name

Comment: Dont have another app with the same name